# Setting permissions umbraco nodes

Tags: c#, visual-studio, umbraco, user-permissions

In Umbraco using Visual Studio and part of the design is to have a way for users to create, lets say, requirements for a client, and then add the descriptions of the requirement.

Now once this is done they can set user permissions to each individual who they want to be able to edit the individual requirements or descriptions, everyone can view but only those people added to the list can edit, from the page where the overall requirements are shown.

This is an internal program and I after a lot of searching i'm having trouble finding exactly what I need or knowing if it is even possible.

I am a complete beginner to this stuff so please feel free to ask more so I can expand on anything that is needed to better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right-click a node in the Umbraco tree, there's a menu item called Permissions. In there, you can edit node permissions for individual users. For easier management, you might want to take a look at this package, which allows permissions to be set in groups: https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/user-group-permissions/

Comment: The package also appears to be able to replace permissions on all underlying nodes, something that you can't do out-of-the-box.

Comment: will that allow the users of the website to add user permissions for their added requirements? It seems like only I can set permissions from that

Comment: Ah, no, sorry. I thought you meant Umbraco users :-s If it's a front end thing, you'll probably have to do something custom with the Membership stuff :-s In Umbraco, the terminology is like users = editors/writers/etc and members = logged in website users.

Comment: Ok thanks, it gets pretty complicated when I think about the users having to be in their separate groups and able to set individual permissions, I still need to find a way of using something like LDAP. It's a bit over my head so hopefully someone can shed some light on the possibility.